# In ci Where_in is not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$menus = implode(',', $menu_id);
$this->db->where_in('rgroup_id',$menus);
$query = $this->db->get('rights_group');
```

please give me suggestion

Comment: are you getting any errors ? did you try to print the formed SQL

Comment: not any error i am getting only one row

Comment: and we have multiple rows in database

Comment: You should not implode the ids

Comment: i have ids in array

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: Now i have tried this $this->db->where('rgroup_id in '.$menus.'');that is working fine

Comment: You can use this. but CI provide proper syntax then it would be great if you use CI proper syntax.
Thanks.

Comment: where_in only accept array as parameter passing string will not work

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code.

```
$menu_id = "1,2,3"; 
$menus = explode(',', $menu_id);
$this->db->where_in('rgroup_id', $menus);
$query = $this->db->get('rights_group');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but if we have already a string so why we explode it.

Comment: we can directly use the string

Comment: Yes, you can use it directly.

Comment: Great now enjoy.

Comment: If you got a correct answer then you can upvote and add as a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use array as value try this

```
$menus = [1, 3, 4];
$this->db->where_in('rgroup_id', $menus);
$query = $this->db->get('rights_group');
```

more : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in

Answer (score 0):

May be bug on Codeigniter,
I copy query and run on mysql and it has no error, but codeigniter still error near WHERE ... IN ()
So I run by native and it work like a charm.

```
$this->db->save_queries = TRUE;
$this->db->from('rights_group');
$query = $this->db->last_query();
return $this->db->query($query)->result();
```

Don't forget: 
$this->db->save_queries = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$this->db->where_in('rgroup_id',$menus);
```

to

```
$this->db->where_in('rgroup_id',$menus,false);
```

Look at the generated query below.

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `my_id` IN(‘1,2,3’)
```

There is a quote before 1 and after 3. The query should be

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `my_id` IN(1,2,3)
```

to work it as expected.

Answer (score -1):

We do not need to implode the array: directly pass array in `where_in`. You will get result. I have tried and it worked.